Question about showing $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/F[x,y]$
Background
Theorem 1:  Let $M$ be an ideal in a commutative ring $R$ with identity $1_R$.  Then $M$ is a maximal ideal if and only if the quotient ring $R/M$ is a field.
Exercsie 1: Prove that $(x)$ and $(x,y)$ are prime ideals in $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ but only the latter ideal is a maximal ideal.
Exercsie 2:  Let $F$ be a field and let $R=F[X,Y](=F[x][Y])$ be the polynomial ring in two variables over $F$.  Show the following.
$(a)$ $RX+RY$ is a maximal ideal of $R$

Solutions:  Suppose $I$ is an ideal which contains $RX+RY$ properly.  Then there is an element $f=f_{00}+Xh+Yk$ in $I$ with $f_{00} = f(0,0)\neq 0$.  So $I$ contains  a unit $f_{00} = f-Xh-Yk\,$ so $\, I = R$.

Questions
I am trying to solve the part of Exercise 1 showing that $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ by understanding the subtlties of how to make use of Theorem 1: and also if possible to use alternate methods like from Exercise 2.
In Theorem 1, to show that $M$ is a maximal ideal in commutative ring $R$, I have to show that the quotient ring $R/M$ is a fieldl.  I am to understanding that the latter means if I don't know whether $R/M$ is a field, but if I know that if $R/M$ is isomorphic to another algebraic object that is a field.  In effect, I have shown that $M$ is a maximal ideal, irrespective of whether I know in advance whether $R$ as a ring is also a field or not??
And so, to do Exercise 2's portion of showing that $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$, I create an evaluation homomorphic map $\varphi:\Bbb{Q}[x,y]\to  \Bbb{Q}$ by defining $\varphi_{\{x,y\}}(f(x,y))=f(0,0)$, with $\varphi$'s kernel being $\varphi_{\{x,y\}}(f(x,y))=f(0,0)=0$ iff any $f(x,y)\in \Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ has constant term equal to $0$, but this is the same as $\sum_{\{i,j\}=1}^{n}r_{ij}x^iy^j\in (x,y)$ with $r_{00}=0$.  How come then solution to Exercsie 2 look so different in the sense that it doesn't use Theorem 1, and only make use of the property: "Let $R$ be a ring with identity and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$.  If $I_R\in I$, prove that $I=R$." Also it seem that the solution avoids knowing whether $F$ is a field or is not a field. Also, I want to know what I can learn from solution to Exercsie 2 as an alternative method of solution.
Thank you in advance.

To finish exercise 1, you can just show that $(x,y)$ is exactly the set of polynomials with zero constant term. The solution for exercise 2 needs $F$ to be a field, so that $f_{00} \ne 0$ implies $f_{00}$ is a unit. I don't understand what you mean by "if $1 \in F$ where $F$ is a ring, then $F$ is a field" - the only way I can make sense of it is false.

@arkeet I edited my post.  it was an earlier exercsie  that came up in Hungerford.;s undergrad text.  I thought Exercsie 2;s solution implicitly relied on that fact.

Please ask only one question per post, and don't add further questions after the post is closed.

@BillDubuque I edited my question to clarify what I am trying to ask.  What i edited is also part of the comments I made.  Nothing new has been added.

HINT:
Consider the homomorphism $\phi: Q[x,y] \to Q$ given by $\phi(f(x,y)) = f(0,0)$. What is the kernel of $\phi$?
Then utilize the first isomorphism theorem for rings to say that $Q[x,y]/\ker \phi \approx Q$. We know that $Q$ is a field and so $\ker \phi$ is maximal by your theorem.

how come Exercsie 2's solution look so different?  I know my question seem to be a bit vauge.  I am just wondering what I can learn from it as an alternate method of solution?
